# Cannot conform to Decodable when using Mirror(reflecting:)

Tags: swift, codable, decodable, mirror

I'm using `Decodable` in order to decode some JSON, all properties on this struct have the same structure it's just the JSON contains them in multiple arrays. The code works until I add another property `let all = Mirror(reflecting: Sizes.self).children`. I'm using this in order to get all the properties so I can loop over the struct to actually injest the data.

The issue I'm having is that when I store `all` as a constant, the code will not compile and gives me the following error:

> Type 'Sizes' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

```
struct SizeJSON: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var width: Double
    var height: Double
}

struct Sizes: Decodable {
    let small: [SizeJSON]
    let medium: [SizeJSON]
    let large: [SizeJSON]
    let all = Mirror(reflecting: Sizes.self).children
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this as a stored property? Can't you create the Mirror object when you need it? Or use CodingKeys enum to tell the decoder which properties to decode.

Comment: I want to define it in one place. When using CodingKeys, the return value of `all` is just 0

Comment: What Joakim means is why this isn't `var all: Mirror.Children { Mirror(reflecting: Sizes.self).children }` rather than a stored property. `Mirror.Children` is not Decodable. Does your Sizes JSON actually contain an `all` key? (If not, then this doesn't make sense. If so, then I assume it's a bunch of Strings, not `Mirror.Children`.) What does the actual JSON look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mirror`'s [init(reflecting:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror/1540715-init) initializer needs to pass an **instance** of your type to work.

You can accomplish what you are trying using a lazy variable, like this:

```
struct Sizes: Decodable {
    let small: [SizeJSON]
    let medium: [SizeJSON]
    let large: [SizeJSON]
    lazy var all: [SizeJSON] = {
        Mirror(reflecting: self).children
            .compactMap { $0.value as? [SizeJSON] }
            .flatMap { $0 }
    }()
}
```

That way you can both have access to `self` instance and avoid for `all` property to be decoded.